# Convert []interface{} into type []string

Tags: go

I have value [token code id_token]  from map, value of map type []interface{}

```
resp := result["response_types"]
```

resp is `type []interface{}`.

i need to convert it to: `clientobj.ResponseTypes`

```
type client struct{
    ResponseTypes sqlxx.StringSlicePipeDelimiter `json:"response_types" db:"response_types"`
}
```

in package sqlxx

```
package sqlxx
type StringSlicePipeDelimiter []string
```

is there is to convert it?

Comment: please open this question, that question not duplicate.
I solve it by marshal and unmarshal .I want to share my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `[]inteface{}` to `[]string`, you just iterate over the slice and use type assertions:

```
// given resp is []interface{}
// using make and len of resp for capacity to allocate the memory in one go
// instead of having the runtime reallocate memory several times when calling append
str := make([]string, 0, len(resp))
for _, v := range resp {
    if s, ok := v.(string); ok {
        str = append(str, s)
    }
}
```

The real question here is how you end up with a variable of type `[]interface{}` in the first place. Is there no way for you to avoid it? Looking at the `StringSlicePipeDelimiter` type itself, it has the `Scan` method (part of the interface required to scan values from the database into the type) [right here](https://github.com/ory/x/blob/v0.0.180/sqlxx/types.go#L21), so I can't help but wonder why you're using an intermittent variable of type `[]interface{}`

Comment: I'm use  intermittent variable of type []interface{}  because I get data from Aerospike data

Comment: that  it returned as type of  aerospike.BinMap , result["response_types"]  is returned value as []interface{}  that I need to convert it to StringSlicePipeDelimiter.